# Waiting for Debugger to connect Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin

After upgrading to Xcode 7 and Xamarin stable release (up to date) i now get the above message after the program successfully compiles

Also when trying to deploy to the device i get the following 
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets: Error: Could not locate the iOS '9.0' SDK usr path at '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.0.sdk' (xxx.myApp.App.iOS)

The SDK's are succesfully loaded when viewed via the preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i switched to Beta mode and everything started compiling and deploying

Everything is up to date regarding Xcode and Xamarin

Answer (score 1):

Same situation here... it makes the SpringBoard process getting high in memory, even if I close Xamarin and the process, it comes back
Then I have to reboot

Should wait a fix...

Answer (score 0):

Did you update to the latest version today: https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-xamarin-ios-support-for-ios-9-xcode-7-final/

Ensure you have the latest official release that support xcode 7 and iOS 9